# Players to score a goal and an own goal in a single World Cup game

Tags: football, trivia, world-cup, own-goal

Mario Mandžukić of Croatia scored two goals in the 2018 World Cup final against France, one of which was an own goal.

How many times has a player scored a goal and an own goal in a single World Cup game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only ***2 times*** a player has scored a goal and an own goal in a single World Cup game.

1. [Ernie Brandts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernie_Brandts) in [a second-round match against Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A#Italy_vs_Netherlands), scored goals for both teams in the same match. [1](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/round=279/match=2391/index.html#nosticky)

[image: e b]
[Source](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/round=279/match=2391/index.html#nosticky)

2. [Mario Mandžukić](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Mand%C5%BEuki%C4%87) in [a FIFA World Cup final match against France](https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/matches/match/300331552/#match-liveblog). [It is the first own goal in World Cup Final history.](https://twitter.com/ESPNStatsInfo/status/1018516378486263808)

[image: source]
 [Source](https://twitter.com/OptaJavier/status/1018538399131725825)

Comment: But the first in a final match

Comment: @JFK Yes, it's a first in a final match.